# Given $W[f,g](t) = t\sin(t)$ find $W[f+g,f-g]$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If the $W[f,g](t) = t\sin(t)$, find $W[f+g,f-g]$. $f$ and $g$ are not given, I wrote down the original equation $fg'-gf'$ to compare to $f+g(f-g)-f-g(f+g)'= t\sin(t)$. I am not sure how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 5):

The Wronskian
$$
 W(f, g) = \begin{vmatrix} f & g \\ f' & g'\end{vmatrix}
$$
“inherits” some properties of the determinant:

- It is linear in each argument.
- It is anti-symmetric, i.e. it changes the sign if two arguments
  are swapped.

(Those properties hold for Wronskians of arbitrary many functions,
but we need it only for two functions here.)

Therefore
$$
 W(f+g, f-g) = W(f, f) + W(f, -g) + W(g, f) + W(g, -g) \\
 = 0 - W(f, g) - W(f, g) + 0 = -2 W(f, g) \, .
$$

Comment: If you're using the properties of the determinant, you might as well note that
$$
W(f+g,f-g) = \det \pmatrix{f+g & f-g\\ f'+g' & f' - g'} = \det \left(\pmatrix{f&g\\f'&g'}\pmatrix{1&1\\1&-1} \right) = W(f,g) \det \pmatrix{1&1\\1&-1}
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Indeed, that is another good insight. – (What I was trying to suggest is that you convince yourself of those two properties once, then forget about the determinant and just expand the expression using these rules.)

Answer (score 0):

Start with $W[f+g,f-g]$ and expand it to get

$$\begin{align}
W[f+g,f-g]&=(f+g)(f-g)'-(f-g)(f+g)'\\
&=ff'-(fg'-gf')-gg'-(ff'+(fg'-gf')-gg')\\
&=-2(fg'-gf')
\end{align}$$

and hence $fg'-gf'$ equals $W[f,g]$, as you already mentioned, we get

$$W[f+g,f-g]=-2W[f,g]=-2t\sin t$$